# Exporting Animation into Unity

Tags: animation, export, unity

I hope you have a wonderful day. I am having a problem with exporting the animation. I've bought an asset from cgtrader which is basically an animated flag with cloth simulation and I've followed this tutorial in order to export cloth simulation into Unity. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=roRaaG_D9d8) I've baked the animation, exported and re-imported the .MDD file in order to create all the keyframes of the animation and then I started to delete the modifiers but when I deleted the cloth simulation and played the animation, the animation was looking weird and flag's position has shifted. I can provide video clips of before and after the deletion. Thanks in advance.